# dynamic import when using babel transpiling in node_module library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, code-splitting

### Situations:

1. I have a **library A** which used **"import"** to split code, and it is a react component library.
2. my project named **B** which depends on the **library A**.
3. the code splitting works perfectly if I import **library A's** source code directly.
4. but if I **transpile** the library A by babel at first, then import the **transpiled code** in **project B**. The effect of code splitting in library A was disappeared.

## Questions:

How can I import library A's transpiled code and keep its code-splitting effect?